# How to use function composition for `foo (bar x) (bar y)` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that in Haskell, there is a awesome feature called **function composition** so that we could make our Haskell code pithier, like:

- use `(f . g) x` instead of `f (g x)`,
- use `foo x $ bar y z` instead of `foo x (bar y z)`

But is it possible that we could use function composition for `foo (bar x) (bar y)`?

Comment: Note that, in the future, you can try using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(b%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20b)%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20c) to search for a function you want, which actually gives a useful answer here. :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `on` function for this, for instance

```
import Data.Function

data Person = Person{name::String, age::Int}

compare `on` age --same as `\x y -> compare (age x) (age y)`
```

Comment: While this is useful thing to know, my feeling is that the "spirit" of the question was much broader than this.  The original question was about--if you might--the "joy and convenience of composition".  In my imagination, it would have been an equivalent question if the request was for **foo (bar x) (bar y) (bar z)**.  That is to say I don't think it was a question about "arity 2"-ness.  As your answer is factual I withheld a downvote...but...it is disappointing to me (in my quest to learn Haskell myself) that this is considered a great answer to what was asked.

Comment: @HostileFork The question used both `(.)` and `($)` as examples of “composition”, so it seems quite likely to me that that question was asked with a more general understanding of “composition” in mind that the simple function composition operator. Haskell has many tools in its toolbox for combining functions, and being able to find the right one for the job is often more important than using the most general possible pattern. That said, your interpretation of the question seems interesting, and I would not mind trying to answer it if you posted it separately, with slightly more specifics.

Comment: @AlexisKing *"so it seems quite likely to me that that question was asked with a more general understanding of “composition” in mind"* - Perhaps just seeing it through a language learner's eyes, I'd argue the opposite--that it indicates a lack of understanding of the distinction of what mathematical composition is.  Really I guess my complaint is just that it's a very hard language to learn, and I don't think it gets easier if you ask something like this and wind up getting `curry (uncurry f . (g *** g))` as an answer, sans explanation.  Just seems like people didn't "hear what was asked"

Comment: @HostileFork For what it’s worth, when I read the question, I thought of the solution using `Control.Arrow`, myself. However, I think a particularly good answer in that vein would use that to demonstrate that sometimes composition is not the clearest tool for the job, and instead it’s better to just write things out in pointful style. This is actually something I’ve very interested in (making Haskell more accessible), so if you’d like to take this conversation to chat, I’d love to! As it is, it’s a bit off-topic here, though, I’m afraid. :)

Comment: @HostileFork I’ve made a room here, if you’d like to chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112357/haskell-conversation-for-alexis-king-and-hostilefork

Answer (score 4):

Define it yourself! Just a new infix function:

```
-- foo (bar x) (bar y) === foo $.$ bar (x y)
($.$) :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> c)
f $.$ g = \x y -> f (g x) (g y)

-- test 3 5 = 3*3 + 5*5
test = (\x y -> x + y) $.$ (\z -> z * z)
```

Then in ghci:

```
ghci> test 3 5
34
```

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible that we could use function composition for `foo (bar x) (bar y)`

@ilyavf has given an answer, for a function definition such that `(foo $.$ bar) x y` will act like `foo (bar x) (bar y)`.  And @jamshidh offers that it exists as `on` in Data.Function.

But notice the type signature of is kind of a specific shape:

```
(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> c)
```

As a function, though, it's "shaped funny" due to an assumption it has to make.  That assumption is that both of `foo`'s arguments are of the same type.  *(otherwise, how could it be correct to use the result of bar for both?)*

The "more pleasing shape" to which Haskell gravitates doesn't call out the special case of working with functions that have two arguments of the same type.  Because what is so special about 2?  Much more interesting is "N", and if your function takes N arguments of the same type, then a list is nicer...and can compose as you would like, with a map operation that could work with any number of arguments:

`foo [bar x, bar y]` => `(foo . map bar) [x, y]`

Comment: @TaylorFausak I'm just learning *(and trying to start learning-by-answering)* so you'll have to explain to me what you mean.  Because I'm just trying things like `concat [show 10, show 20] => "1020"` and then `(concat . map show) [10, 20] => "1020"` and conclude it must work.  But I'm quite ready to be wrong wherever anything Haskelly is concerned.

Comment: I would say a list is too specific. If your function takes exactly two (or three, or four) arguments, then using an intermediate list will inject partiality. You can instead use an arbitrary `Functor`, which will allow lists, custom tuple types, length-indexed lists (i.e., dependent vectors), etc.

Comment: @dfeuer "inject partiality" is a bit opaque to a self-proclaimed beginner.  I already am trying to understand *"That won't work if `bar` is, say, `show`"*.  So I can't tell if you're just saying "use fmap instead of map" (which I didn't do deliberately for didactic purposes, as it would introduce functors and Fness, and be tangential, though I'm in the "map should be fmap camp"--I think--still new, so I could be wrong).  If you're saying something more than that, you'd have to walk through it more carefully.

Comment: @HostileFork I meant that you can't pull the `show` out of the list if you're applying it to different data types. `[show 1, show "two"]` works fine, but `map show [1, "two"]` is an error.

Comment: @TaylorFausak Ok, so **on** fixes this?

Comment: No, `on` requires both arguments to be the same type.

Comment: @TaylorFausak Ok, so why is the comment on my answer?

Comment: No reason other than that's when I realized it was a problem. If you want to apply a type class function to multiple data types, you'll have to do it manually. None of these solutions will work.

Comment: @TaylorFausak, I bet you could do it with `HList` and a helper class, probably using `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `ConstraintKinds` for generality.

Answer (score 2):

A `Control.Arrow` alternative:

```
curry (uncurry f . (g *** g))
```

Not as readable as the previously posted solutions.

Comment: `on g f = (. f) . g . f`

Comment: Why would you do something so horrible? Ewww!

Comment: @user3237465 I like this one the most.

Answer (score 2):

Pointless equivalences for `\x y -> foo (bar x) (bar y)`:

- [Data.Function.Meld](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-meld-0.1.1.0)

  ```
  foo $* bar $$ bar *$ id
  ```
- [Control.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.11/docs/Control-Compose.html)

  ```
  (bar ~> bar ~> id) foo
  ```
- [Data.Function.Tacit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-tacit-0.1.0.0) (uses -XTypeApplications)

  ```
  lurryA @N2 (foo <$> (bar <$> _1) <*> (bar <$> _2))
  lurryA @N4 (_1 <*> (_2 <*> _3) <*> (_2 <*> _4)) foo bar
  ```

Comment: That's interesting (and yet another distinct interpretation of the OP's intent with the question...which may be the right one, though it would suggest the framing should have been **foo (bar x) (baz y)**)